# module.export is exporting object instead of string stored in variable

Tags: javascript, module, electron, node-modules, module.exports

When I use module.exports and add a string at the end it exports and shows correctly in the string but when I export a variable instead it returns an object {}.

This is the code from the export.js file

```
    clientList = document.getElementById("client-list")
    aLink = document.getElementsByClassName('a-link')
    var exVariable;
    function myFunction(event) {
        event.target.setAttribute('href', 'clientinfo.ejs')
        var variable = event.target.innerText
        exVariable = variable
        console.log(exVariable)
        return exVariable  
}    
if (exVariable != null) {
    module.exports = exVariable
}
```

Over here myFunction executes onclick event.

And this is the code from the import folder which logging out an empty object in the console.

```
var clientFolder = require('./export.js')
console.log(clientFolder)
```

Comment: Thats terrible. what are you trying to archiv with that ?

Comment: I am trying to export the value of a single variable or use that variable in another file can you please tell me the correct way ?

Comment: @Marc I am trying to export the value of a single variable or use that variable in another file can you please tell me the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is modules are generally cached after they're first "require"d. In node there is a whole [require.cache](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) system that you can read up about. Since I see you're using `document`, I suspect these files are being bundled for the browser via something like webpack. In that case, to the best of my knowledge there isn't a way to do that without really messing with webpack internals.

But the even shorter answer is: don't do that. Whatever you're trying to do, this is not the way to do it.